# how to make lined circle with turtle in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

[How to make draw like this with  turtle?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP6gK.png)

right now my code looks like that:

```
class OperationsOnSets():

def __init__(self):
    self.font_style = ("Times New Roman", 40, "bold")

def move_turtle_pos(self, x, y, turtle):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.setpos(x, y)
    turtle.down()

def set_d(self):
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.pensize(2)
    turtle.speed(2)

    self.move_turtle_pos(-100, -50, turtle)
    turtle.circle(200)

    self.move_turtle_pos(100, -50, turtle)
    turtle.circle(200)
    sleep(5)
    turtle.mainloop()

example = OperationsOnSets()
example.set_d()
```

and here is [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3obi.png)

I though about pasting image, or make algorithm that would draw a lines, but I don`t know how to realize it. So  I hope that someobody  of you will help me with it...

Comment: Circles are routine work for the turtle. But the hatches raise a true challenge. You need to find the coordinates of the endpoints of every segment. This can be done by establishing the equations of the parallel lines and finding their intersections with the two circles. This takes the resolution of quadratic equations. By choosing the correct endpoints, you can obtain the desired segments. Notice that the letter A appears inside a smaller empty circle. By finding the intersections with the latter, you can also obtain the interruptions of the segments. Drawing the letters is more classical.

Comment: OMG it`s sound really hard, I misunderstood what should I do even with google translate

Comment: @YvesDaoust maybe you know how to do it in easier way, for example with TKinter

Comment: The difficulty is not in the language or graphical toolset, it lies in the coordinate computation. Unless the toolset supports drawing a filled square with a circular hole, or complex shapes with hatches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My philosophy of turtles, is avoid the math by getting the turtle to do the hard work for you.  Not quite perfect, but pretty close:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

RADIUS = 200
NUMBER_LINES = 14

class OperationsOnSets():

    def __init__(self):
        self.turtle = Turtle()
        self.turtle.pensize(2)
        self.turtle.fillcolor(screen.bgcolor())

    def move_turtle_pos(self, x, y):
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.setpos(x, y)
        self.turtle.pendown()

    def set_d(self):
        self.move_turtle_pos(-RADIUS/2, -RADIUS)

        points = []
        for _ in range(NUMBER_LINES):
            self.turtle.circle(RADIUS, 180 / NUMBER_LINES)
            points.append(self.turtle.position())

        for _ in range(NUMBER_LINES):
            self.turtle.circle(RADIUS, 180 / NUMBER_LINES)
            position = self.turtle.position()
            self.turtle.goto(points.pop())
            self.turtle.goto(position)

        self.move_turtle_pos(RADIUS/2, -RADIUS)
        self.turtle.begin_fill()
        self.turtle.circle(RADIUS)
        self.turtle.end_fill()

        self.move_turtle_pos(-RADIUS/2, -RADIUS)
        self.turtle.circle(RADIUS, 180)

        self.turtle.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()

example = OperationsOnSets()
example.set_d()

screen.mainloop()
```

We make the turtle stop along its way around the circle to record points we'll need to finish the drawing.

[image]

Comment: thanks, you helped me a lot. If it possible, could you please explain me why and how it`s work. Why "-Radius" why "180" etc.

Comment: @МиколаВаськевич the `RADIUS` is just your 200 radius parameterized so we can change the size of the circles without having to check every line of code.  The 180 represents the degress in half a circle as I draw the circle in halves: one half where I collect points; one half where I draw lines.  I also do a final "half" to redraw the perimeter where it got wiped out by the second circle fill.